# Get function pointers from anonymous function in userscript

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I'm new here, excuse me if i'm not speaking english very good. I'm using JavaScript for 1-3 months, so here maybe will be *very stupid* question or ideas. Please tell me where i'm wrong. Thanks you.

I have a problem with my userscript: i need to get pointers to call some functions from one site. Structure of site script is like

```
(function(a, b) {
    var c = {
        d: true
    };
    var e = function(f) {
        g();
    }
})(jQuery, window);
```

I need to access `e` function in my userscript. Is it even possible? If it's not, how can it be done other way? (I need to call that function manually from my script)

Please, answer. Thanks.

Comment: Side note: In JavaScript, they're called function *references* rather than function pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `e` variable is declared inside a function and isn't either used as the return value or assigned to anything outside of the function, it is completely private. You can't access it from outside the function.

If you *want* do, you can change it so you can:

```
(function(a, b) {
    var c = {
        d: true
    };
    b.e = function(f) {
        g();
    }
})(jQuery, window).
```

There, we assign `e` as a *property* on `window` (indirectly through your `b` argument). `window` properties are globals, so now you have a global variable `e`.

(I don't recommend globals, though.)

Comment: I don't have access to rewrite code (i can only create userscript). That JS code is on site

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, what you've shown is a very effective way of making variables/functions "private" - they can't be accessed from outside. However, it may be possible to access e if it's set to a property in jQuery, or window (`window` is the object that contains all global variables).

Since I doubt that your target looks exactly as you've specified, you should probably investigate it more closely to see what happens to `e`, and whether it gets assigned someplace you can use it. In other words, I don't have all the information for a complete answer.

Comment: Thanks you. Tell me, can i get that function if it's called from other function? May be like stacktrace or something?
To be more correct: button has function `a` attached to it (`a` is private). When `a` is called (button pressed), `b` is called from `a`. Can i get that `b`?

Comment: Get it from where? Obviously `a` has it, but...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder
Look.

`... var b = function(c) {;} 

var a = 1; 

button.click(function() {b(a);}) ...` _(inside that anonymous function)_

 Can i get reference to `b` by extracting `a` from `_data('events')`? Can i get it any other way?
If not, what is other way to call `b`? I cannot copy it, because it uses private members of that anonymous function.

Comment: JavaScript does not have any browser-consistent method of doing a stack trace. You *might* be able to simulate a click on a button using some libraries, but based on the short example given in your comment, I can't think of any way to grab B.